# I have come across a problemin my code, and i cannot fix it, i don't know how. (More Detail Below)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    If TextBox1.Text = ("Meme101") Then
        Dim color = TextBox1.ForeColor As("Blue")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

> The "As", Just After "TextBox1.ForeColor", Has An Error Saying "Expected End Of Statement" I've Tried End Sub And End If, And One More (Forgot), But It Still Expects An End Of Statement. What Other End Of Statement Can I Possibly Do?

[My Code, As A Screenshot In Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCtDi.png)

Comment: Can you clarify your intention? Do you want to use a color name (a string) to set the `ForeColor`, or you just don't know how to set it in any other way? You should also remove the brackets from here: `("Meme101")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"As" is a *type definition* keyword, so you should use it like this:

```
Dim c as Color
c = Color.Blue
TextBox1.ForeColor = c
```

Or simply:

```
 TextBox1.ForeColor = Color.Blue
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following [Color.FromArgb Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.fromargb?view=netframework-4.8), you can use it to customize colors:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        If TextBox1.Text = "Meme101" Then
            'Opaque colors (alpha value defaults to 255 -- max value)
            Dim blue As Color = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 255) '(Red,Yellow,Blue)
            TextBox1.ForeColor = blue
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Result：

[image]